# what happened when delete array element in awk?

Tags: awk

I wrote the following code :

```
awk -F"\t" '{
    a[1]=1; a[2]=2; a[3]=3; a[4]=4; a[5]=5; 
    delete a[4]; 
    print "len", length(a); 
    for( i =1; i<=length(a); i++) 
        print i"\t"a[i] 

    for( i in a) 
        print i"\t"a[i]
}' -
```

And the output is:

```
len 4
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   
5   5
4   
5   5
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

my question is as I have deleted the 4th element and the length of the array `a` has become 4, so why there is still 5 elements with the value of the 4th elements become blank when I print the array? Does that indicate that 'delete' only delete the value and the corresponding index remains?

Answer (score 7):

Remove the middle `for` loop and you'll see what's happening:

```
$ echo x | awk -F"\t" '{
    a[1]=1; a[2]=2; a[3]=3; a[4]=4; a[5]=5; 
    delete a[4]; 
    print "len", length(a); 
    for( i in a) 
        print i"\t"a[i]
}'

len 4
2   2
3   3
5   5
1   1
```

The delete is working as you expect, removing the array element with index 4, leaving 4 elements with indices 1, 2, 3, and 5. (Even though you are using numeric indices, it's still an associative array and the old `a[5]` is *not* now accessible as `a[4]` --- it's still `a[5]`.)

The reason you're seeing five elements in your example is the middle `for` loop:

```
for( i =1; i<=length(a); i++) 
    print i"\t"a[i]
```

By simply referring to `a[4]` in the above print statement, you are recreating an element of the `a` array with that index having an empty value.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. the length of array incease by 1 after referring to `a[4]`

Comment: @ningyuwhut Yes, accessing an array element is enough to "initialize" it so your middle loop was recreating that deleted entry.